# Passed variable returns null

Tags: ios, objective-c, null, parameter-passing

When I pass a variable to another view it always returns 'null'

Code **Screen1.m**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"gotoScreen2"])
    {
        Screen2 *screen = [[Screen2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        Screen2.passedVar = currentVar;

        NSLog(@"%@",currentVar); //these 2 line both return the correct var!
        NSLog(@"%@",Screen2.passedVar);
    }
}
```

Code **Screen2.h**

```
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *passedVar;
```

Code **Screen2.m**

```
@synthesize passedVar;
...
NSLog(@"%@",passedVar); //This returns 'null'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the line `Screen2.passedVar = currentVar;` is incorrect since classes cannot have instance variables. But even if you replaced this line with the seemingly correct `screen.passedVar = currentVar;`, it would not work as you expect.

Your mistake is that you are creating a new instance of the destination view controller `Screen2` in `perpareForSegue:sender:`. The system will just ignore this object and it well get deleted when the method returns.

The system will create an instance of `Screen2` for you when you ask it to perform the segue. You access this instance in `prepareForSegue:sender:` via the `segue` parameter:

```
Screen2 *screen = (Screen2 *)segue.destinationViewController;
screen.passedVar = currentVar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes can't have ivars, and you're not assigning the ivar to the object (aka class instance), but to the class itself, which does not have sense. Try this:

```
Screen2 *screen = [[Screen2 alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
screen.passedVar = currentVar;
NSLog(@"%@",screen.passedVar);
```

Also remember that `screen` points to a newly created `Screen2` object, it does not have anything to do with the controller that is being presented.